# Errors on terminal for using auto and enum class feature of c++, how to fix it?

Tags: xubuntu, c++

I am new to Ubuntu environment. I am using gcc 5.2.0 version. C++14 installed I believe.

Error:

```
a5.cpp: In member function ‘void Board::initOthello()’:
a5.cpp:208:27: error: ‘Color’ is not a class or namespace
             board[i][j] = Color::none;
a5.cpp:394:14: error: ‘priority’ does not name a type
         auto priority = getPriority(possibilities[i], board);
a5.cpp: In member function ‘void Game::printState()’:
a5.cpp:437:10: error: ‘scores’ does not name a type
     auto scores = board.getScores();
```

There are no errors or problems when I run the code on my school's ubuntu system.  The only problem happens when I run it at home.

### Question:

Is there any way I can add 'enum class' and 'auto' and 'static variables' on terminal ?

Comment: Is there something like sudo ... that I can enter to update or install a key feature of Ubuntu ?

Comment: Edit your question to include the actual command used to compile the code as well. Also, [GCC 5.2 uses C++98 as the default standard (with extensions)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Standards.html).

Comment: You can specify the dialect explicitly on the command line e.g. `g++ -std=c++11`

Comment: @muru, yes you were right. It was c++98.

Comment: @steeldriver, thank you so much. Yes that was what I needed to do, run  the program with that, but I did c++14 instead, but it worked.

Comment: g++  -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wno-sign-compare -Wnon-virtual-dtor -g   a5.cpp   -o a5  

this was what I used.